# Safe to set CGEvent user data field?

Tags: macos, core-graphics, keyboard-events, core-foundation, cgeventtap

The [`CGEvent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgevent) type allows setting integer values for a specified list [`CGEventFields`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgeventfield), one of which is the [`eventSourceUserData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgeventfield/eventsourceuserdata) field. Is it safe to set this field to any value as determined by the program sending the event?

**Background / Use Case**

A `CGEventTap` is setup and running on a `CFRunLoop`. On receiving an event, we might want to send multiple events rather than modifying the current event. For example, on receiving a keydown 'a' event, send 2x of keydown 'b' and keyup 'b' events so the output is 'abb'.

However, we don't want the events for 'b' to flow back through the `CGEventTap`. If they did, and we had another rule for sending 2x 'c' events on receiving a 'b' event then the output would be 'abccbcc' which is not what we want.

For the 'b' events being sent, we can set the `eventSourceUserData` field to some magic number. Then, when an event is received by the `CGEventTap` we can check the user data, and nullify the event if it contains the magic number.

Here's the pseudocode.

```
tap = CGEventTap(..., function(event) {
  if (event.eventSourceUserData == MAGIC) {
    event.setType(NULL)
    return
  }
  
  if (event.getType() == KEYDOWN && event.getKeycode() == 'a') {
    eventBDown = createEvent(KEYDOWN, 'b').withEventSourceUserData(MAGIC)
    eventBUp = createEvent(KEYUP, 'b').withEventSourceUserData(MAGIC)
    
    loop twice {
      eventBDown.post()
      eventBUp.post()
    }
  }
})

CFRunLoop.runWithTap(tap)
```

Comment: Have you tried? Does it work? Is `MAGIC` the same for all posted events? Can't you use `CGEvent.tapPostEvent(_:)`?

Comment: Yes, `MAGIC` is the same for all posted events. And it does work, but the Apple Developer docs aren't very clear to me if it is safe to set arbitrary user data for `CGEvent`. So I'm not sure if there's a risk of overwriting data that the OS relies on. Thanks for mentioning `tapPostEvent`, I hadn't seen that.

Comment: @Willeke confirmed that `CGEvent.tapPostEvent` solves this issue as well.

Comment: Do you use your own event source?

Answer (score -1):

In a similar situation, I’ve used the keyboard type event field to mark events that I created. I am not sure that’s safer than what you are doing.